# Why I am getting "0" value in a last column "Total_Monthly_Amount"?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, export-to-excel, epplus

[image]

Getting zero as a calculated value and formula also is present.
My moto is to group by Amount based on EmployeeId.
I want to use Automatic calculation method for last column but when I try to create file it shows me zero.

FORMULA is also present for respective "0" value field.

I am using EPPLUS 4.0 and also setting formulas:

Like in code

> "IF(" + currentCell + "=" + previousCell + ",\"\",SUMIF(B:B," +
>   currentCell + ",I:I))";

Instead of first "0" value will be "18000"
Instead of Second "0" value will be "32987"
and so on.

```
using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
            {


                ExcelWorksheet workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                excel.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
                workSheet.TabColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                workSheet.DefaultRowHeight = 12;
                //Header of table  
                //  
                workSheet.Row(1).Height = 20;
                workSheet.Row(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                workSheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;

                List<string> employeeIds = new List<string>();
                int cntrSameEmployeeId = 1;
                int cntrFormulaManipulate = 0;

                ds.Tables[0].Columns.RemoveAt(0);


                for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[1, i].Value = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                }

                int setLastColumnName = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count + 1;
                workSheet.Cells[1, setLastColumnName].Value = "Total_Monthly_Amount";

                for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; k++)
                    {
                        if (employeeIds.Contains(Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[k])))
                        {
                            cntrSameEmployeeId++;
                        }
                        if (k + 1 == 2)
                        {
                            if (!employeeIds.Contains(Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[k])) && employeeIds.Count != 0)
                            {
                                cntrSameEmployeeId++;
                            }
                            employeeIds.Add(Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[k]));
                        }
                        if (k == (ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1))
                        {
                            if (cntrFormulaManipulate == 0)
                            {
                                workSheet.Cells[j + 2, ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count + 1].Formula = "IF(B2=B1,\"\",SUMIF(B:B,B2,I:I))";
                                cntrFormulaManipulate++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string currentCell = "B" + (cntrSameEmployeeId + 1).ToString();
                                string previousCell = "B" + cntrSameEmployeeId.ToString();
                                string maniPulateFormula = "IF(" + currentCell + "=" + previousCell + ",\"\",SUMIF(B:B," + currentCell + ",I:I))";
                                workSheet.Cells[j + 2, ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count + 1].Formula = maniPulateFormula;
                                //workSheet.Cells[j + 2, ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count + 1].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Double;
                                //workSheet.Cells[j + 2, ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count + 1].Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
                            }
                        }
                        workSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Value = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[k]);

                    }

                }

                //workSheet.Cells["A27"].Formula = "=SUM(B2:B10)";

                workSheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

                excel.Workbook.Calculate();

                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path1 + @"\FormulaExample.xlsx");
                excel.SaveAs(fi);

            }
```

Comment: Your numbers are stored as text and the SUMIF can't add text.

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you please elaborate with example so I will undestand more quickly what are you trying to say. Because same logic has worked in " Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to fix your code, don't know C#.  I know formulas, and since your numbers are being inputted as text (hover over the green triangles and you will get the message) SUMIF will ignore them.  You need to convert the numbers stored as text to real numbers for the formula to work.

Comment: Thank you so much.I got your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.I have just converted ToString() to Int32() for AMOUNT field value.

```
workSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[k]);
```